# Google Webmaster Tools says my XML sitemap "appears to be an HTML page"

Tags: html, google-search-console, sitemap, iis, xml

We're running a lot of sites and we've started to get a lot of these errors in Webmaster Tools:

> Sitemap is HTML
> Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead.

One of the problematic sitemaps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.same_domain.co.uk/folder/file1.shtml</loc> 
        <lastmod>2011-05-11</lastmod> 
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
        <priority>0.5</priority> 
    </url> 
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.same_domain.co.uk/folder/file2.shtml</loc> 
        <lastmod>2011-05-11</lastmod> 
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
        <priority>0.5</priority> 
    </url> 
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.same_domain.co.uk/folder/file3.shtml</loc> 
        <lastmod>2011-05-11</lastmod> 
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
        <priority>0.5</priority> 
    </url> 
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.same_domain.co.uk/folder/file4.shtml</loc> 
        <lastmod>2011-05-11</lastmod> 
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
        <priority>0.5</priority> 
    </url> 
</urlset>
```

### Why would GWTs think this is anything but XML?

(Server: IIS)

---

#### Edit:

> "This document was successfully checked as well-formed XML!" -W3C Validator.

---

### Edit:

I resubmitted two problematic sitemaps, one with no changes, and one with a couple of extra lines to ensure it's treated as XML. Ran the "Fetch as Googlebot" diagnostic tool. Both are fine now. I'm just going to re-submit all sitemaps with the "Sitemap is HTML" error

The question remains:

## Why did this happen? Why did GWTs think these XML sitemaps were HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farseeker's suggestion is a good first step in troubleshooting (a `text/html` content-type would certainly produce this result) - Google Webmaster Tools should display a *different* error message if the sitemap file contains invalid XML.

Given the temporary nature of the issue, have you checked your server logs to determine whether an error page was produced on Google's prior requests?

If you are dynamically generating sitemap files, a scripting error, database timeout, or other issue could produce an HTML error page intermittently.

Comment: An error message from the server would definitely send out HTML headers and is a very plausible explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the `content-type` header that it's spitting out. Inspect it with your favourite tool (Firebug, etc) and see what it's sending.

Comment: Nope. `Content-Type text/xml`

Comment: @Adam Lynch - The correct content type is `application/xml` (Edit: A review of [RFC 3023](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3023#section-3.2) leaves some ambiguity on this point, but try the `application` type for troubleshooting) ... Strike that - tested and GWT works with either content-type.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the header to include the schema stuff:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

and then [validate online](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

If it passes that it must be Google's problem.

Comment: "Line 2 (`<urlset>`): 192 SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd' must have even number of URI's. 
Line 2: 192 cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'urlset'"

Comment: Sorry, it was a cut and paste error. I've fixed it now. I also found out that the xmlvalidation website doesn't work properly if you're using that text box. You have to refresh the page and then paste in again to get it to revalidate properly.

Comment: `"No errors were found"` but does that mean that this **will** solve the errors? We have a lot of sitemaps

Comment: It means it's valid, so I guess it's Google's problem. You could report it on the webmaster forums http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/label?lid=401d0e67c19e20e9&hl=en with all the info you've put here (right content type, extension, valid XML).

Comment: I've now added the schema attributes & values you've given so I'm [waiting to see if the problem is gone](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14130/when-does-google-webmaster-tools-re-evaluate-re-submitted-sitemaps)

Comment: They aren't necessary according to the minimal sitemap example on http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php, however they do mean the XML validator can check the file, and won't do any harm.

Comment: Ok then, I'll post in the forum

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any issues from the web server side. Or if the Google IP is blocked. If you are using any log based tracking system, try to analyse the Google Bot activity. We recently had the same issue and found out that as Google changed its IP address, we were not allowing google bots to crawl through due to data mining. Issue was finally resolved.