# When does Google Webmaster Tools re-evaluate re-submitted sitemaps?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

When I alter and re-submit a sitemap does GWTs immediately re-evaluate it or do I have to wait 'til GoogleBot crawls our site again?

I just re-submitted a problematic sitemap and it now displays the green tick next to it but does this really mean it is valid? I need to know is [the problem](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14121/google-webmaster-tools-says-my-xml-sitemap-appears-to-be-an-html-page/) really solved.

#### Edit:

[Google Webmaster Central says](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35738):

> "Once you've reviewed your Sitemap and made any changes, save it and then resubmit it. It can take up to a day for Google to process the resubmitted Sitemap, so the warning status may continue to display until then."

I would use this to answer the question, **but** does this actually mean that my problem is gone? (*Because the icon changes from a red X (error) to a green tick (valid)*).
**I'm not so sure.**
I simply resubmitted one problematic sitemap **without any changes** and the icon changed.

#### Edit:

On the details page of a problematic sitemap I re-submitted, the Downloaded date is today's that. **Does this guarantee the error was fixed?** Because the Downloaded date is today for both sitemaps I re-submitted (see edit #1)

Comment: I think your problem is solved if you don't see any warnings/errors

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use [this tool](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) to create your sitemap if you don't already. Download the uncompressed xml one and put it at the root of your domain.

Now, when it comes to re-evaluating sitemaps, GWT does it almost instantaneously when you re-submit it, but for the changes to actually be taken into account by the internet as a whole, you'll have to wait till Google recrawls your site, yes.

Anybody feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that's how it goes ;)

Comment: Have a look at the edit

Answer (score 0):

I have a site with over 300,000 links and 30 different site maps.  I found that, after I change my site maps and resubmit, Google continued to crawl my site using the old site maps for a few days.

I had a major issue involving double urlencoding as stated [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59553/do-google-sitemap-urls-need-to-be-double-urlencoded)

On the first day, Google gave me over 1000 errors involving urlencoding.  I fixed the problem and resubmitted my site maps, but for two days, the errors kept coming.  I had to continually mark errors as fixed and eventually the errors stopped coming.

There is lag time, so be sure to make you sitemaps a accurate as possible the first time and wait a day or two before judging the effects of an update