# Do Google sitemap URLs need to be double urlencoded?

Tags: google-search-console, url, sitemap, url-encoding

Do Google sitemap URLs need to be double `urlencoded`?

I am submitting my sitemaps to Google and Google is having difficulty navigating to URLs that contain `urlencoded` characters.  An example of a problematic URL is one that contains `here&there` (which has been `urlencoded` to `here%26there`).  In my sitemap, this URL looks like this:

```
example.com/here%26there
```

However, Google misreads my sitemap and searches for:

```
example.com/here&there
```

which returns a 404 error.  Do I need to double encode the URL in my sitemap so that it looks like this:

```
example.com/here%2526there
```

(note that `%` becomes `%25`)

Although this question is about Google and the way it reads sitemaps ((do Google sitemap URLs need to be double `urlencoded`)), I'll go ahead and show you guys the code I'm using to double encode my URLs for my sitemaps:

```
for($j = 1; $j <= $page_count; $j += 1){

   $data .= '<url><loc>'.str_replace('%', '%25', 
      BASE_URL.'products/'.
      urlencode(str_replace('/', '~1', $list['manufacturer']))).
      ($j == 1?'':'/'.$j).'</loc></url>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note that non-URL '/'s are completely removed and all other special characters are double encoded.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957115/is-a-slash-equivalent-to-an-encoded-slash-2f-in-the-path-portion-of-a  -- Slash and %2F are often viewed as interchangeable in URLs.

Comment: I have been using the "Fetch as Google" option within Google's web master tools.  I'm 99% sure that I need to double encode my URLs.  Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: You'd need to deal with the special characters with whatever code constructs the URL's in your sitemap. Without seeing that code, it's hard to give advice. If you use `preg_replace` you can handle characters such as `&` (it would be recommended to handle these in the URL's as well, even if replacing them with a hyphen or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I when ahead and submitted my site maps to Google with Double urlencoding.  In other words, if a URL contained a urlencoded character, such as %26, this became %2526

My 404 errors are now down from 14,000 to 10,000 and are still dropping.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use `preg_replace` with `urldecode` in the URL construction to retain special characters in the URL such as what are currently in your sitemap.

```
preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($[attach_necessary_object_here]));
```

This way the URL's would be:-

```
example.com/here/there
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your regular expression, I'm not quite sure what it does.

Comment: It replaces and decodes %252F etc back to special characters such as / (slash) in this example.

Comment: Although this is not quite the solution I was looking for (the slashes definitely need to be encoded), I would like to know more about this regular expression usage.  I understand how ([0-9a-f]{3,4}) works, but the rest is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Actually, something seems to be amiss.  You regex returns %2F for %252F instead of /

Comment: Without seeing the code of your website, is hard to give you an exact working line. I recently used my answer to retain slashes in an input field and it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I did not give enough details in my question.  I don't want to alter the urls in my site, I just want to create a sitemap that works.  I'll update my question.

Comment: Although you code is useful, it does not answer my greater question.  I know how to encode and double encode.  I really want to know if I should (for Google.)